# Data Migration Using SSIS (64 bit oracle)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, bids

Scenerio : Data Migration from Oracle 11g(64 bit) to SQL Server Azure.
Tried : I was using SSIS and found that their is an issue with bit size that visual studio comes only in 32 bit for BIDS.
Question :I can't change the Oracle bit size as this one is used by client.
Can anyone give me any idea how to do that?

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem, the bit-ness of the installs shouldn't affect the ability for SSIS to move data. Is it a problem installing SSIS on a 64-bit box?

Comment: I am using the 64 bit operation system(Windows).Visual Studio for SSIS is 32 bit and the oracle server 11g is of 64 bit

Comment: Do you get an error message? I can use Oracle connector in 32 bit in SSIS, just make sure to run the package as 32 bit compatibility.

Comment: Visual Studio 32-bit will install fine onto a 64-bit Windows machine. The fact that the data source (Oracle) is running on a 64-bit machine is immaterial. SSIS operates at the data record level, it doesn't do anything fancy at OS level.